# How to download filename.xml uploaded to Azure Storage container using Terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-storage, terraform-provider-azure

Was able to Upload blob using below . Looking for similar TF code to either get the contents of the file (Or) download the file using Terraform code

```
resource "azurerm_storage_blob" "example" {
  name                   = "example-blob"
  storage_account_name   = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
  storage_container_name = azurerm_storage_container.example.name
  type                   = "Block"
  source                 = "/path/to/local/file.txt"
  
  metadata = {
    "foo" = "bar"
    "hello" = "world"
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have referred below Terraform code from these two Official Terraform [Document-1](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/storage_blob)
& [Document-2](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/local/latest/docs/resources/file) to download the files from Azure blob.

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

data "azurerm_storage_account" "rkdestorage" {
  name                = "rkdestorage"
  resource_group_name = "RK-DataExplorer-Training"
}

data "azurerm_storage_container" "sample-100" {
  name                 = "sample-100"
  storage_account_name = data.azurerm_storage_account.rkdestorage.name
}

data "azurerm_storage_blob" "sample_blob" {
  name                   = "date.txt"
  storage_container_name = data.azurerm_storage_container.sample-100.name
  storage_account_name   = data.azurerm_storage_account.rkdestorage.name
}

resource "local_file" "sample" {
  content  = data.azurerm_storage_blob.sample_blob.name
  filename = "C:\\date.txt"
}
```

**Output:-**

**Terraform Apply:**

[image]

I downloaded the  **‘date.txt’**  file from the  **Azure blob**  to my local directory.

[image]

Once ran the above terraform code file got downloaded to local path successfully.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure how this would work, the name attribute of the data azurerm_storage_blob will just be the name of the blob, not the contents. I'd expect your `C:\\date` file to be completely empty, or--at best--just contain `date.txt`

Comment: If the 'C:\date' file needs to be completely empty, please modify the file path according to your requirements. Then, test it with my code and share the results so that I can further assist you in modifying my answer based on your requirements.